# How to use the for loop with function needing for a string field?

Tags: r, for-loop, statistics, binning

I am using the **smbinning** R package to compute the variables information value included in my dataset.

The function `smbinning()` is pretty simple and it has to be used as follows:

```
result = smbinning(df= dataframe, y= "target_variable", x="characteristic_variable", p = 0.05)
```

So, `df` is the dataset you want to analyse, `y` the target variable and `x` is the variable of which you want to compute the information value statistics; I enumerate all the characteristic variables as `z1, z2, ... z417` to be able to use a for loop to mechanize all the analysis process.

I tried to use the following for loop:

```
for (i in 1:417) {
 result = smbinning(df=DATA, y = "FLAG", x = "DATA[,i]", p=0.05)
  }
```

in order to be able to compute the information value for each variable corresponding to `i` column of the dataframe.

The `DATA` class is "data.frame" while the `result`one is `"character"`.

So, my question is how to compute the information value of each variable and store that in the object denominated `result`?

Thanks! Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps, you need `... x = names(DATA)[i], ...` or `... x = DATA[, i], ...`? `"DATA[, i]"` won't treat "i" differently in each iteration as it is just part of a string. E.g. see `for(i in 1:3) print(paste("var_i"))` VS `for(i in 1:3) print(paste("var_", i, sep = ""))`. And, depending on what "result" is, you'll need something like `result[i]` or `result[i, ]` or `result[, i]`...

Comment: Hi @alexis_laz and thanks for the comment! Result is a list composed by 7 elements by construction e called result$Cutpoint, result$CntRec, ...; I particularly need of the IV value one can find by typing result$iv and store that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No sample data is provided I can only hazard a guess that the following will work:

```
results_list = list()    
for (i in 1:417) {
    current_var = paste0('z', i)
    current_result = smbinning(df=DATA, y = "FLAG", x = current_var, p=0.05)
    results_list[i] = current_result$iv
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay and thanks for the answer! Do you know a way to add to you the rest of the bounty?

Answer (score 5):

You could try to use one of the `apply` methods, iterating over the z-counts. The `x` value to `smbinning` should be the column name not the column.

```
results = sapply(paste0("z",1:147), function(foo) {
   smbinning(df=DATA, y = "FLAG", x = foo, p=0.05)
})
class(results) # should be "list"
length(results) # should be 147
names(results) # should be z1,...
results[[1]] # should be the first result, so you can also iterate by indexing
```

I tried the following, since you had not provided any data

```
> XX=c("IncomeLevel","TOB","RevAccts01")
> res = sapply(XX, function(z) smbinning(df=chileancredit.train,y="FlagGB",x=z,p=0.05))
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion 
> class(res)
[1] "list"
> names(res)
[1] "IncomeLevel" "TOB"         "RevAccts01"
> res$TOB
...
```

HTH